# Accessing element of a multidimensional array of strings in C

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this multidimensional array of strings in C and I want to access a specific value without doing a loop. Is it possible?

I've tried accessing the strings in the array using 
printf("Test %c", *pitchtomidi[0][4]) but I'm always only given the first character of the string and not the whole string. I've tried replacing %c with %s but I get this error:

```
"warning: format specifies type 'char ' but the argument has type 'char' [-Wformat]"
```

Here's the array:

```
char *pitchtomidi[104][8] = {
     {"24", "32.7", "B#0", "ty0", "C1", "do1", "Dbb1", "ru1"},
     {"25", "34.64444318554896", "C#1", "di1", "0", "0", "Db1", "ra1"},
     {"26", "36.7045089797165", "Cx1", "dy1", "D1", "re1", "Ebb1", "mu1"},
     {"27", "38.887072660588984", "D#1", "ri1", "0", "0", "Eb1", "me1"},
     {"28", "41.19941833156236", "Dx1", "ry1", "E1", "mi1", "Fb1", "fu1"},
     {"29", "43.64926323136014", "E#1", "my1", "F1", "fa1", "Gbb1", "su1"},
     {"30", "46.24478348960022", "F#1", "fi1", "0", "0", "Gb1", "se1"},
     {"31", "48.994641413867505", "Fx1", "fy1", "G1", "so1", "Abb1", "lu1"},
     {"32", "51.90801439936015", "G#1", "si1", "0", "0", "Ab1", "le1"},
     {"33", "54.99462555759296", "Gx1", "sy1", "A1", "la1", "Bbb1", "tu1"},
     {"34", "58.264776166378226", "A#1", "li1", "0", "0", "Bb1", "te1"},
     {"35", "61.7293800493828", "Ax1", "ly1", "B1", "ti1", "Cb2", "du2"},
     {"36", "65.40000000000005", "B#1", "ty1", "C2", "do2", "Dbb2", "ru2"},
     {"37", "69.28888637109796", "C#2", "di2", "0", "0", "Db2", "ra2"},
     {"38", "73.40901795943304", "Cx2", "dy2", "D2", "re2", "Ebb2", "mu2"},
     {"39", "77.77414532117801", "D#2", "ri2", "0", "0", "Eb2", "me2"},
     {"40", "82.39883666312477", "Dx2", "ry2", "E2", "mi2", "Fb2", "fu2"},
     {"41", "87.29852646272032", "E#2", "my2", "F2", "fa2", "Gbb2", "su2"},
     {"42", "92.48956697920049", "F#2", "fi2", "0", "0", "Gb2", "se2"},
     {"43", "97.98928282773505", "Fx2", "fy2", "G2", "so2", "Abb2", "lu2"},
     {"44", "103.81602879872034", "G#2", "si2", "0", "0", "Ab2", "le2"},
     {"45", "109.98925111518597", "Gx2", "sy2", "A2", "la2", "Bbb2", "tu2"},
     {"46", "116.5295523327565", "A#2", "li2", "0", "0", "Bb2", "te2"},
     {"47", "123.45876009876564", "Ax2", "ly2", "B2", "ti2", "Cb3", "du3"},
     {"48", "130.80000000000015", "B#2", "ty2", "C3", "do3", "Dbb3", "ru3"},
     {"49", "138.57777274219598", "C#3", "di3", "0", "0", "Db3", "ra3"},
     {"50", "146.81803591886614", "Cx3", "dy3", "D3", "re3", "Ebb3", "mu3"},
     {"51", "155.54829064235608", "D#3", "ri3", "0", "0", "Eb3", "me3"},
     {"52", "164.7976733262496", "Dx3", "ry3", "E3", "mi3", "Fb3", "fu3"},
     {"53", "174.5970529254407", "E#3", "my3", "F3", "fa3", "Gbb3", "su3"},
     {"54", "184.97913395840104", "F#3", "fi3", "0", "0", "Gb3", "se3"},
     {"55", "195.97856565547016", "Fx3", "fy3", "G3", "so3", "Abb3", "lu3"},
     {"56", "207.63205759744073", "G#3", "si3", "0", "0", "Ab3", "le3"},
     {"57", "219.978502230372", "Gx3", "sy3", "A3", "la3", "Bbb3", "tu3"},
     {"58", "233.05910466551305", "A#3", "li3", "0", "0", "Bb3", "te3"},
     {"59", "246.91752019753133", "Ax3", "ly3", "B3", "ti3", "Cb4", "du4"},
     {"60", "261.60000000000036", "B#3", "ty3", "C4", "do4", "Dbb4", "ru4"},
     {"61", "277.15554548439206", "C#4", "di4", "0", "0", "Db4", "ra4"},
     {"62", "293.63607183773246", "Cx4", "dy4", "D4", "re4", "Ebb4", "mu4"},
     {"63", "311.0965812847124", "D#4", "ri4", "0", "0", "Eb4", "me4"},
     {"64", "329.5953466524994", "Dx4", "ry4", "E4", "mi4", "Fb4", "fu4"},
     {"65", "349.1941058508816", "E#4", "my4", "F4", "fa4", "Gbb4", "su4"},
     {"66", "369.95826791680236", "F#4", "fi4", "0", "0", "Gb4", "se4"},
     {"67", "391.9571313109406", "Fx4", "fy4", "G4", "so4", "Abb4", "lu4"},
     {"68", "415.26411519488175", "G#4", "si4", "0", "0", "Ab4", "le4"},
     {"69", "439.95700446074426", "Gx4", "sy4", "A4", "la4", "Bbb4", "tu4"},
     {"70", "466.1182093310264", "A#4", "li4", "0", "0", "Bb4", "te4"},
     {"71", "493.83504039506295", "Ax4", "ly4", "B4", "ti4", "Cb5", "du5"},
     {"72", "523.200000000001", "B#4", "ty4", "C5", "do5", "Dbb5", "ru5"},
     {"73", "554.3110909687844", "C#5", "di5", "0", "0", "Db5", "ra5"},
     {"74", "587.2721436754651", "Cx5", "dy5", "D5", "re5", "Ebb5", "mu5"},
     {"75", "622.193162569425", "D#5", "ri5", "0", "0", "Eb5", "me5"},
     {"76", "659.1906933049991", "Dx5", "ry5", "E5", "mi5", "Fb7", "fu7"},
     {"77", "698.3882117017636", "E#5", "my5", "F5", "fa5", "Gbb5", "su5"},
     {"78", "739.916535833605", "F#5", "fi5", "0", "0", "Gb5", "se5"},
     {"79", "783.9142626218817", "Fx7", "fy7", "G5", "so5", "Abb5", "lu5"},
     {"80", "830.5282303897641", "G#5", "si5", "0", "0", "Ab5", "le5"},
     {"81", "879.9140089214892", "Gx5", "sy5", "0", "0", "A5", "la5"},
     {"82", "932.2364186620536", "Bbb5", "tu5", "A#5", "li5", "Bb5", "te5"},
     {"83", "987.6700807901268", "Ax5", "ly5", "B5", "ti5", "Cb6", "du6"},
     {"84", "1046.400000000003", "B#5", "ty5", "C6", "do6", "Dbb6", "ru6"},
     {"85", "1108.6221819375698", "C#6", "di6", "0", "0", "Db6", "ra6"},
     {"86", "1174.5442873509314", "Cx6", "dy6", "D6", "re6", "Ebb6", "mu6"},
     {"87", "1244.3863251388511", "D#6", "ri6", "0", "0", "Eb6", "me6"},
     {"88", "1318.3813866099995", "Dx6", "ry6", "E6", "mi6", "Fb6", "fu6"},
     {"89", "1396.7764234035285", "E#6", "my6", "F6", "fa6", "Gbb6", "su6"},
     {"90", "1479.8330716672115", "F#6", "fi6", "0", "0", "Gb6", "se6"},
     {"91", "1567.8285252437647", "Fx6", "fy6", "G6", "so6", "Abb6", "lu6"},
     {"92", "1661.0564607795295", "G#6", "si6", "0", "0", "Ab6", "le6"},
     {"93", "1759.8280178429798", "Gx6", "sy6", "A6", "la6", "Bbb6", "tu6"},
     {"94", "1864.4728373241085", "A#6", "te6", "0", "0", "Bb6", "te6"},
     {"95", "1975.340161580255", "Ax6", "ly6", "B6", "ti6", "Cb7", "du7"},
     {"96", "2092.8000000000075", "B#6", "ty6", "C7", "do7", "Dbb7", "ru7"},
     {"97", "2217.244363875141", "C#7", "di7", "0", "0", "Db7", "ra7"},
     {"98", "2349.088574701864", "Cx7", "dy7", "D7", "re7", "Ebb7", "mu7"},
     {"99", "2488.7726502777036", "D#7", "ri7", "0", "0", "Eb7", "me7"},
     {"100", "2636.7627732200003", "Dx7", "ry7", "E7", "mi7", "Fb7", "fu7"},
     {"101", "2793.5528468070584", "E#7", "my7", "F7", "fa7", "Gbb7", "su7"},
     {"102", "2959.6661433344243", "F#7", "fi7", "0", "0", "Gb7", "se7"},
     {"103", "3135.657050487531", "Fx7", "fy7", "G7", "so7", "Abb7", "lu7"},
     {"104", "3322.1129215590604", "G#7", "si7", "0", "0", "Ab7", "le7"},
     {"105", "3519.656035685961", "Gx7", "sy7", "A7", "la7", "Bbb7", "tu7"},
     {"106", "3728.9456746482183", "A#7", "li7", "0", "0", "Bb7", "te7"},
     {"107", "3950.6803231605113", "Ax7", "ly7", "B7", "ti7", "Cb8", "du8"},
     {"108", "4185.600000000016", "B#7", "ty7", "C8", "do8", "Dbb8", "ru8"},
     {"109", "4434.488727750283", "C#8", "di8", "0", "0", "Db8", "ra8"},
     {"110", "4698.177149403729", "Cx8", "dy8", "D8", "re8", "Ebb8", "mu8"},
     {"111", "4977.545300555408", "D#8", "ri8", "0", "0", "Eb8", "me8"},
     {"112", "5273.525546440002", "Dx8", "ry8", "E8", "mi8", "Fb8", "fu8"},
     {"113", "5587.105693614118", "E#8", "my8", "F8", "fa8", "Gbb8", "su8"},
     {"114", "5919.3322866688495", "F#8", "fi8", "0", "0", "Gb8", "se8"},
     {"115", "6271.3141009750625", "Fx8", "fy8", "G8", "so8", "Abb8", "lu8"},
     {"116", "6644.225843118122", "G#8", "si8", "0", "0", "Ab8", "le8"},
     {"117", "7039.312071371923", "Gx8", "sy8", "A8", "la8", "Bbb8", "tu8"},
     {"118", "7457.8913492964375", "A#8", "li8", "0", "0", "Bb8", "te8"},
     {"119", "7901.3606463210235", "Ax8", "ly8", "B8", "ti8", "Cb9", "du9"},
     {"120", "8371.200000000033", "B#8", "ty8", "C9", "do9", "Dbb9", "ru9"},
     {"121", "8868.977455500568", "C#9", "di9", "0", "0", "Db9", "ra9"},
     {"122", "9396.35429880746", "Cx9", "dy9", "D9", "re9", "Ebb9", "mu9"},
     {"123", "9955.090601110818", "D#9", "ri9", "0", "0", "Eb9", "me9"},
     {"124", "10547.051092880005", "Dx9", "ry9", "E9", "mi9", "Fb9", "fu9"},
     {"125", "11174.211387228237", "E#9", "my9", "F9", "fa9", "Gbb9", "su9"},
     {"126", "11838.664573337703", "F#9", "fi9", "0", "0", "Gb9", "se9"},
     {"127", "12542.628201950129", "Fx9", "fy9", "G9", "so9", "Abb9", "lu9"}
};
```

Thanks!

Comment: `%s` is right, but `*pitchtomidi[0][4]` should be `pitchtomidi[0][4]` without the `*`

Comment: Thank you! That's the answer.

Comment: Unrelated to the question, you should change the declaration to `const char *pitchtomidi[104][8]`.

Comment: @Lundin thanks, I made the change. I presume it's to be safe in case I unintentionally override the values when they are meant to remain the same.

Comment: @NakulTiruviluamala It needs to be `const` since you _can't_ change the values, they are all read-only string literals.

Answer (score 1):

As Blaze pointed out, `%s` is right, but `*pitchtomidi[0][4]` should be `pitchtomidi[0][4]` without the `*`